# Chirps Monthly mean Data for multiple points or region using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Using the this Code (https://code.earthengine.google.com/3491eb14052114811c048687b7885bf7) I am trying to obtain monthly mean time series of precipitation data (chirps) of multiple location. I have 2 queries

1. how can I get time series in same graph for these six location? I tried using ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion but I am getting error stating - Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"
2. How can I get Single Mean value of the month of a year for each of these.

'''

```
var r = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.15067,9.34339), {'label': 'Anathode Dam'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.06994606,8.954271389), {'label': 'Kallada dam'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(76.74478393,9.852621715), {'label': 'Mallankar dam'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(75.82326883,11.59669815), {'label': 'Kuttiyadi Dam'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(76.53852053,10.98574468), {'label': 'kanhira Dam'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(76.79667658,10.62448299), {'label': 'Meenkara Dam'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.14592432,8.535029363), {'label': 'Neyyar dam'})
]);
Map.addLayer(r);


var precip1year=chirps.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31');
var TS2 = ui.Chart.image.series(
  precip1year, r,  ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000, 'system:time_start')
  .setOptions({
        title: 'Monthly precipitation',
        hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Precipitation (mm)'}
  });
  
print(TS2)

var precip1year=chirps.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2019-01-01');
var TS2 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  precip1year, r,  ee.Reducer.mean(),'precipitation', 1000, 'system:time_start', 'label')
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
        title: 'Monthly precipitation',
        hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Precipitation (mm)'},
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 4,
          series: {
           0: {color: 'FF0000'}, 
           1: {color: '00FF00'}, 
           2: {color: '0000FF'},
            3: {color: '#27c8ff'}, 
            4: {color: 'Orange'}, 
            5: {color: 'Purple'},
            6: {color: '#ff58fe'},
}});
print(TS2);
```

Comment: Apparently I just saw 2 Bug reports and few people discussing about the same error that I am getting i.e. Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start", so I guess there is some issue with GEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the post Comment, it was a bug. Upon reporting it to google, it was rectified. The Script works Perfectly.